# Flutter Local File Downloader

Tags: flutter-downloader

Here I need some help about flutter local file downloading. Currently I am use this code to download Web local file(PDF)

**here is code :**

```
savePDF(
  var bytes,
  OnlineOrderDetailsModel itemsDetails,
) {
 html. AnchorElement(
      href:
          "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,${base64.encode(bytes)}")
    ..setAttribute('download', "${itemsDetails.onlineOrder!.id}.pdf")
    //..setAttribute('_blank', "$orderId.pdf")
    ..click();
}
```

**generate pdf at the end:**

```
  List<int> bytes = await pdf.save();
  savePDF(bytes, itemsDetails);
```

Now I want to download local file from My Android Application. If anyone have any solution
Please share your repository...

Thanks